# Transfinite ordinals as indices of set

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to understand how the transfinite ordinals work, so I tried to come up with an example of a set of numbers with an element at a transfinite index:

Let the totally ordered set $X = \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},\dots\} \cup\{1\}$ be ordered according to the standard ordering of the rational numbers. Would I be correct in assuming that $X_\omega=1$ since it is the first number in the set with an infinite index? If not, what does it mean to find $X_\omega$ and which at index *would* $1$ be?

Likewise, if I ordered the set $Y=\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},\dots\}\cup\{1+\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{3}{4},1+\frac{7}{8},\dots\}\cup\{2\}$ in the same way, would $Y_{2\omega} = 2$? If not, what would be the index $i$ where $Y_i = 2$?

Comment: Yes, $X_\omega=1$ and $Y_{\omega+\omega}=2.$ However, according to the convention for ordinal multiplication that I learned, $$\omega+\omega=\omega2\ne2\omega=\omega.$$ Are they teaching a different notation nowadays? What book are you using?

Comment: @bof I'm just using Wikipedia and SE. If $\omega+\omega \neq 2\omega$, what would $Y_{2\omega}$ mean?

Comment: Like I said, $2\omega=\omega,$ so $Y_{2\omega}=Y_\omega=\frac32.$ In the traditional notation, $\omega2=\omega+\omega,$ and $2\omega=2+2+2+\cdots=\omega.$ They may seem backwards but it makes the laws of exponentiation come out right: $\alpha^{\beta+\gamma}=\alpha^\beta\alpha^\gamma$ and $(\alpha^\beta)^\gamma=\alpha^{\beta\gamma}.$

Comment: See the Wikipedia article about [ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication).

Comment: A set $S$ is an ordinal iff (1) $S$ is transitive, which means every member of $S$ is a subset of $S,$ and (2) $S$ is well-ordered by $\epsilon.$  A well-order is a linear order in which every non-empty subset has a least member. The arithmetic order on the rationals or reals is NOT a well-order... Any well-ordering on a set is order-isomorphic to the $\epsilon$-ordering on a unique ordinal.

Comment: @user254665 My set has a least element: $X_0=\frac{1}{2}$. In what way is it not a well ordering? Also, what does it mean for a set to be well-ordered by $\epsilon$?

Comment: @ostrichofevil $1/4 < 1/2$, $1/8 < 1/4$, and so on, so your set has no least element and is not well ordered.  However, if you reverse the ordering of just that rational numbers of $X$ so that $1/4 > 1/2$ etc but $\forall x \in X: x = 1 \lor x < 1$, then it is a well-order and order-isomorphic to $\omega + 1$.

Comment: A linear order is a well-order iff every non-empty subset  S has a least  member within S. For a set to be well-ordered by any binary relation  R, the relation R must be satisfy the conditions in the def'n of a linear order, and also be a well-order.

Comment: @DanSimon I actually made a bit of a mistake when I asked this question! $X$ was originally meant to equal $\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},\dots\} \bigcup \,\{1\}$, which would, of course been a well ordering. I forgot that I had actually written $\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\dots\}$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**. I was $\TeX$ blind and I took the order in which the sets were written above, not the one inherited from the real line. I'm modifying my answer according to the intent in the OP's [comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097009/transfinite-ordinals-as-indices-of-set/2097684?noredirect=1#comment4313420_2097009).

---

Some pieces of useful information:

- Ordinals can be regarded as types of isomorphism of well-orders. Hence two well-orders of the same “shape” have the same ordinal.
- The ordinal sum $\alpha+\beta$ is “$\alpha$, then $\beta$”: Take any well-order of type $\alpha$, stick a well-order of type $\beta$ to the right and that new well-order has type $\alpha+\beta$.
- The product $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is “$\alpha$, $\beta$ times”: Place copies<sup>1</sup> of $\alpha$ in a row so that the set of such copies are in order type $\beta$. Alternatively, take a copy of $\beta$ and replace each of its elements for a copy of $\alpha$.
- The “transfinite index” of any element $x$ in a well-order (actually, this is called its **rank**) is the order type of the **set of elements below $x$**.

So, using your examples, the well-order
$$
\textstyle X = \bigl\{\overbrace{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},\dots}^{\text{type }\omega}\bigr\} \cup \overbrace{\{1\}}^{\text{type }1}
$$
is of type $\omega+1$ and the rank of $1$ is $\omega$.
In $Y$,
$$
\textstyle Y=\bigl\{\overbrace{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},\dots}^{\text{type }\omega}\bigr\}\cup\bigl\{\overbrace{1+\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{3}{4}}^{\text{type }2},1+\frac{7}{8},\dots\bigr\}\cup\{2\},
$$
the rank of $1+\frac{7}{8}$ is $\omega+2$, and $Y\setminus\{2\}$ is the result of replacing each element in a copy of the ordinal $2$ (say, $\{0,1\}$) by a copy of $\omega$ (namely, $\bigl\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},\dots\bigr\}$ and $\bigl\{1+\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{3}{4},1+\frac{7}{8},\dots\bigr\}$). Hence its order type is $\omega\cdot2$ (which equals $\omega+\omega$) and therefore the rank of $2$ is also $\omega\cdot2$.

Finally, for your question on a set being well-ordered by $\in$, you should learn about the [**von Neumann ordinals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals).

---

<sup>1</sup> A *copy* of $\alpha$ is (for the purposes of this answer) a well-order of type $\alpha$.

Comment: If you were to keep doing this, in order to get the set $ A = \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\dots\}\bigcup\,\{1+\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{4},1+\frac{1}{8},\dots\}\bigcup\,\{2+\frac{1}{2},2+\frac{1}{4},2+\frac{1}{8},\dots\}\bigcup\dots\bigcup\,\{\omega\}$, would the rank of $\omega$ be $
\omega^2$?

Comment: @ostrichofevil Yes, if both of us pay attention to __what @DanSimon said above__! I'm going to fix my answer accordingly; I suggest you do the same. Btw, use `\cup` with no additional spacing for binary unions.

Comment: I'll do so. Thanks for the $\LaTeX$ tip!